# LoopTool Circle creates a 'big umbrela'

Tags: vertices

I am trying to use LoopTool Circle to create shape as in Pic# 01.

[image: expectation]

But instead this is what i get .. the LoopTool circle creates something like  abig umbrella. ANy idea why? Thanks

[image]

Comment: F9, take a screenshot of your parameters, in particular, I'd look into the factor if it's not bigger than 1...

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't work (not sure why), instead you can try a Alt Shift S > To Sphere and choose a Factor 1 in the Operator Box

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady -- the factor is exactly 1.

Comment: @moonboots -- OMG .. you are my saviour. It works!!!! Thanks

Comment: @TC. can you please mark moonboots answer as Answer so the question can be closed. Click the checkmark below the votes count on the left of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes *LoopTools > Circle* doesn't work (not sure why), instead you can try a <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *To Sphere* and choose a *Factor* of 1 in the *Operator Box*:

[image]